# How can I convert a ZipWriter to Bytes in Rust?

Tags: post, rust, zip, byte

I want to create a zip from a certain file, then i convert this zip (A buffer, not a file in the disk) to bytes, then to send it by a post body to an api.

Thats the code (simplifyed) just with the essencial, and from now to the next step, how can i convert it into bytes?

```rust
pub fn to_zip() {
    let buf: &mut [u8] = &mut [0u8; 65536];
    let w = std::io::Cursor::new(buf);
    let mut zip = zip::ZipWriter::new(w);

    // * Convert the buffer to bytes

    zip.finish().unwrap();
}
```

Sorry for a maybe confuse code first time with Rust beeing loving it so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip.finish().unwrap()` gives you the `Cursor` that you used to create the `ZipWriter`. You can then use [`into_inner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html#method.into_inner) to go back to a `&mut [u8]`.